# What's the execution sequence of promise in javascript?

Tags: javascript, promise

I am confused of the output of this code.
The output is `4 3 2 1`

How do I understand the flow?

```
new Promise(resolve => {
    resolve(1);
    Promise.resolve().then(() => console.log(2));
    console.log(4);
}).then( t => console.log(t) );
console.log(3);
```

Comment: synchronous code remains synchronous, asynchronous code remains asynchronous - you can see the execution sequence of the console.log's from the output

Comment: 1, 2, 3 (up to .then), 4, 5 (up to .then) 6,3 (code inside .then), 5 (code inside .then) - or, see https://jsfiddle.net/gzy6ncz3/

Comment: What output did you expect? There are links to a video and some documentation in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47678417/1641941) answer that could help.

Comment: Thinking of `resolve()` doing something like a `setTimeout(later, 0)` where `later` is then function registered using `then` could be a good way to reason about what is happening no? I mean that is what it meas to say this is `asynchronous`. It gets pushed to the event-loop right?

Answer (score 3):

I think the key understandings are

- a `new Promise` callback is always invoked synchronously (during the call)
- a `then` callback is always invoked asynchronously (later)

So the individual synchronous steps here are, in order:

```
new Promise(resolve => { // begins creating a promise
    resolve(1);          // fulfills the promise
    Promise.resolve()    // creates a promise
    .then(…);            // registers a callback
    console.log(4);      // logs the first line
})                       // finishes the promise creation
.then(…);                // registers a callback
console.log(3);          // logs the second line
```

When the callbacks are registered, `then` checks whether the promise is already settled, and this is the case here (for both promises), it immediately schedules them by putting them on a queue. In theory this queue defines a specific order, in practice you should ignore that (i.e. things scheduled at the same time can happen in any order). If you want a specific order, always make an explicit promise chain instead of relying on internal queuing.

So here we have two scheduled items:

```
() =>          // the first item is called with undefined (result of `Promise.resolve()`)
console.log(2) // logs the third line

t =>           // the second item is called with 1 (from the `resolve(1)` call)
console.log(t) // logs the fourth line
```

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the way `Promise` is implemented. `Promises/A+ specification` needs the function registered using `then`, say `later`, to be done `asynchronously`.

So, thinking of `resolve(1)` doing something like the below can help you reason about the `asynchronous` flow explained in the above comments:

1. Set the `promise`'s value to 1
2. Register a `setTimeout(later, 0)`, where later is the function
   registered by `then`

`setTimeout` is the key, it just pushes it to the `event-loop` instead of doing it right away because spec says so.

So in,

```
new Promise(resolve => {
    resolve(1);
    Promise.resolve().then(() => console.log(2));
    console.log(4);
}).then( t => console.log(t) );
console.log(3);

console.log(2) // gets queued
console.log(4) // gets executed
console.log(3) // gets executed
console.log(1) // gets queued
```

You can see a related questions here: [Why do Promise libraries use event loops?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23447876/why-do-promise-libraries-use-event-loops)